# Why does mogrify resize a PNG to a width of 50 pixels instead of 50% as specified in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick, mogrify

With some help I've made this code:

```
mkdir SDtemp
copy *@2x*.png SDtemp
mogrify -format png -resize 50% SDtemp/*@2x*.png
pushd SDtemp

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.png) do (
    set "filename=%%~nxa"
    set "purged_filename=!filename:@2x=!"
    ren %%~nxa !purged_filename!
)

endlocal
move *.png ..
popd
rmdir /s /q SDtemp
```

I think, my problem is on this line:

```
   mogrify -format png -resize 50% SDtemp/*@2x*.png
```

It doesn't resize correctly. An image that was 320x320 is now 50x50 and another image that was 600x140 is 50x12, really weird.

I want it to resize like this: 320x320 -> 160x160

Edit: I found the problem, I had to write `%%` because `%` is a special character.

Comment: Try using quotes: `'50%'`.

Comment: with quotes it doesn't resize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double percent-signs:

```
mogrify -format png -resize 50%% SDtemp/*@2x*.png
```

Comment: I found it out after I posted this question, I should really wait a little bit before I ask questions here. Thanks anways! : )